# How to fix a 404 problem related to URL Segment in Typo3 v9.5.9

Tags: typo3-9.x

I'm using an Typo3 new updated website 9.5.9, www.mywebsite.com/mypage1 url generate a 404 page, but when i try this www.mywebsite.com/mypage1?no_cache=1 is working.

I have already tried empty cache.
I also tried upgrading from 9.5.7 tp 9.5.9.

Code error is : 404 Not Found.
Any body have some idea ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server admin have found the problem, it was from nginx server configuration under etx/nginx i don't know what he really changed but it is not a typo3 problem.

Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

Either the Site Configuration is wrong or not set. Check the Base URL .

Or your URL Slug of that page is different than you expected. Maybe TYPO3 added a "1" at the end of the URL Slug, because that excact URL Slug is already being used somewhere in the Database (See Tables "pages", Field "slug"). If you need it to be that excact URL Slug, then delete the wrong page in the database and after that recreate the URL Slug in the page settings.